# Difference between "IntelliJ", "Maven" and "Gradle" build system in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build-system

What is the difference between `IntelliJ`, `Maven` and `Gradle` build system in IntelliJ IDEA?
Has IntelliJ IDEA its own build system?
[image: IntelliJ IDEA - New Project]
In addition, what is the difference between `run` in IntelliJ and Gradle `bootRun`?

Comment: It's integrated support for gradle, which is a completely distinct build system from the IDE. The IDE will use whatever build system you choose, but defaults to `javac`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Build project is IntelliJ's own built-in build mechanism, it simply compiles all modified and dependent files in the project.

However, it's a "plain vanilla" build. It doesnt do fancy things like creating artifacts, deploying to repositories, codegen from a wsdl - etc. That's what we use build automation tools for, and there are 2 of them (`maven` and `gradle`) in widsepread use.

Maven and gradle allow developers to set up a custom (and more complex) build configuration.

The maven `pom.xml` defines lifecycle goals and the gradle `build.gradle` defines tasks.

Via a plugin architecture, maven / gradle can accomplish almost anything in a build process. Whilst the maven / gradle "run" task can operate similarly to IntelliJ "Build Project", it's not the same thing - in this case the build is instrumented by the build tool (maven or gradle) and can be configured differently, and be part of a more complicated build process.

Additionally, maven has build "profiles" that can build the project in different ways.

Answer (score 5):

I tested this locally in my project, using two builds: one using IntelliJ IDEA's "build project" and the second using Gradle's own build command.

Then I checked the contents of the `.build` directory in my project and found that the former (IntelliJ IDEA's build) produced less files than the latter (Gradle). I think Gradle's build system is more powerful than IntelliJ IDEA's, which is why I prefer to use Gradle in my projects.

Answer (score 3):

> What is difference build project in IntelliJ and gradle build?

IntelliJ build uses IDE's own [`jps` project model](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/jps/model-api/src/org/jetbrains/jps/model/JpsModel.java) and [builder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-and-builder.html) for compiling the java-based projects. Including incremental build support.

With Gradle build it actually uses [Gradle](https://gradle.org) to build the project (think Gradle `build` task).

> In addition, What is difference run in IntelliJ and gradle bootRun?

Basically same as above: IntelliJ runner - uses build results of IDE's builder and IDE's own Run/Debug Configuration to launch the application ant tests. With Gradle runner - IDE delegates this to corresponding (`bootRun`) Gradle task.

See also [Configure the build and run actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle) for additional details.